# Windows 8.1 Acer v5 blackscreen how to safe mode

Tags: windows-8.1, acer-aspire, black-screen-of-death

After the Acer logo loads, it turns into blackscreen. How can I go to safe mode?

Comment: Continuously press F8 for entering SAFE MODE. F2 or Delete is usually for BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Cancel the boot, by pressing the [power button to shutdown the Laptop 3 times](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/20140430Defrag#time=19m43s) and after this, Windows boots into the recovery options, where you can select Safe mode.

Comment: This worked for me when F8/shift-F8 didn't. Solved the problem.